# Return all possible paths, having built a predecessor dictionary in Python

Tags: python, search, graph

If I have a predecessor dictionary for a single direction graph generated, such as:

```
{'A': [], 'B': ['A'], 'C': ['B'], 'D': ['B', 'C'], 'E': ['D']}
```

How could I:

1) find all possible paths from point A to E and print them?

Thank you!

Code pasted below:

Code clarification:

G is a tuple of tuples, the inner tuples being pairs of vertices that are connected in one way: ((begin, end) (begin,end))

s is start node

e is end node

```
def dfs_stack(G,s,e):
    stack = [s] 
    vertices = set([j for t in G for j in t]) 
    visited = dict([(v, False) for v in vertices])
    predecessor = dict([(v, []) for v in vertices])
    while stack:
        u = stack.pop()
        if visited[u] == False:
            visited[u] = True
            for w in get_neighbors(u, G): 
                if visited[w] == False:
                    predecessor[w].append(u)
                    stack.append(w)
                elif (visited[w] == True and w != e):
                    return 'CYCLICAL GRAPH'
    return predecessor_to_path(predecessor,s, e)

def predecessor_to_path(pdict, s, end, l=[]):
    l.append(end)
    if end == s:
        return l
    else:
        for p in pdict[end]:
           return predecessor_to_path(pdict, s, p, l)
```

Currently, this only returns the shortest path. Any ideas on how predecessor_to_path could be modified to return ALL paths?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do?  `G` is the graph? `s` is a stack? Of what?  `e` isn't used at all?  Longer variable names and comments are remarkably useful.

Comment: @gfortune added some comments, apologies for the misclarity

Comment: Are you looking for all paths or all _shortest_ paths? Number of all paths could become really big even if you avoid the cycles.

Comment: I am looking for ALL paths. Just added some code to indicate what I have so far in finding all paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all done with classic graph algorithms, like depth-first search.

Here is a starting point:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree#Algorithms

Comment: Thanks. I used a DFS to return the predecessor dictionary, I am still stuck on how to extract the total number of paths from the code and how to detect whether its cyclical though. I will shortly paste what I have so far.

Comment: About cycles: Starting from a node P, if you traverse to its neighbor C that is already marked as visited, there is a potential cycle there. To confirm the cycle, you have to check whether C has a path to P.

Comment: About total number of paths; this will not pop out directly from a depth first search because a DFS obviously avoids traversing all possible paths by checking for already visited nodes. Also, if any of the nodes on any of the possible paths from A to E are involved in a cycle, then then number is paths is infinite.

Comment: thanks, I dont know if the question is updated for you, but I have a check for cyclicality. The only issue remaining is to return all possible paths from a predecessor dictionary.

Comment: Suppose that you're traversing a DAG (a tree with no cycles, but shared substructure). The number of possible paths num(G) can be defined recursively. For an empty graph, or a graph with only one node, the number is zero. For a graph H formed by connecting a node N to a single existing graph G, then num(H) == num(G). If a H is formed by connecting a node to a bunch of different graphs, then num(H) is the product of the num's of all the graphs being connected.

Comment: check out my updated function. I just tried to recursively get all the paths, but it only returns the shortest path as of now.

Comment: It's tedious to think about how to extend your search function, because it's imperative with explicit stack management. I would rather think about this problem in a recursive way, get it working and then think about the imperative rewrite as an optimization based on the recursive logic. (Or else, find a textbook iterative algorithm which already extracts the properties I want, like number of possible paths, and just implement it exactly.)

Comment: I guess what Im asking is: Given a predecessor dictionary such as {NODE:[list of predecessor nodes],..}, is it possible to generate a list of all valid paths? From what I read, there is a solution to this. That is what Im asking. Thanks for your responses.